# IndexOf not working, and can't parse JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to find the position of an array out of a json file. But when I try it with an indexOf I keep getting -1

I also tried parsing it without success.

```
console.log(data.prices.market_hash_name.indexOf("AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)"))
```

is also not working
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'prices.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    contentType: "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
       $(data.prices)  

console.log(data.prices.indexOf("AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)"))

        
    }
});
```

here is the json file:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "prices": [
    {
      "app_id": "730",
      "context_id": "2",
      "market_hash_name": "'Blueberries' Buckshot | NSWC SEAL",
      "price": "1.44",
      "pricing_mode": "market",
      "skewness": "-0.01",
      "created_at": 1609156019,
      "icon_url": null,
      "name_color": null,
      "quality_color": null,
      "rarity_color": null,
      "instant_sale_price": null
    },
    {
      "app_id": "730",
      "context_id": "2",
      "market_hash_name": "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)",
      "price": "58.16",
      "pricing_mode": "market",
      "skewness": "0.09",
      "created_at": 1609152514,
      "icon_url": null,
      "name_color": "D2D2D2",
      "quality_color": "EB4B4B",
      "rarity_color": null,
      "instant_sale_price": "23.26"
    },
    {
      "app_id": "730",
      "context_id": "2",
      "market_hash_name": "'Two Times' McCoy | TACP Cavalry",
      "price": "0.86",
      "pricing_mode": "market",
      "skewness": "0.11",
      "created_at": 1609166685,
      "icon_url": null,
      "name_color": null,
      "quality_color": null,
      "rarity_color": null,
      "instant_sale_price": null
    },
 ]
}
```

Comment: If you can't parse the JSON, as you say, then why would you expect `indexOf` to work? Fix the first problem first.

Comment: i mean that parsing it didnt make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prices is an array of objects; your indexOf call is searching for a specific property value, so it won't find it without some additional help. There are lots of ways to do this, but here's one.

You can use filter to search your array of objects for matches and return the index of the first match if one is found and -1 if none are found.

The function `objIndexOf` I've written here takes in the array to search, the object property to test, and the value you're searching for.

```js
var json = {
  "status": "success",
  "prices": [
    {
      "app_id": "730",
      "context_id": "2",
      "market_hash_name": "'Blueberries' Buckshot | NSWC SEAL",
      "price": "1.44",
      "pricing_mode": "market",
      "skewness": "-0.01",
      "created_at": 1609156019,
      "icon_url": null,
      "name_color": null,
      "quality_color": null,
      "rarity_color": null,
      "instant_sale_price": null
    },
    {
      "app_id": "730",
      "context_id": "2",
      "market_hash_name": "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)",
      "price": "58.16",
      "pricing_mode": "market",
      "skewness": "0.09",
      "created_at": 1609152514,
      "icon_url": null,
      "name_color": "D2D2D2",
      "quality_color": "EB4B4B",
      "rarity_color": null,
      "instant_sale_price": "23.26"
    },
    {
      "app_id": "730",
      "context_id": "2",
      "market_hash_name": "'Two Times' McCoy | TACP Cavalry",
      "price": "0.86",
      "pricing_mode": "market",
      "skewness": "0.11",
      "created_at": 1609166685,
      "icon_url": null,
      "name_color": null,
      "quality_color": null,
      "rarity_color": null,
      "instant_sale_price": null
    },
 ]
};

function objIndexOf(arr, key, value)
{
  var matches = arr.filter(x => x[key] == value);
  if(matches.length <= 0) return -1;
  return arr.indexOf(matches[0]);
}

console.log(objIndexOf(json.prices, "market_hash_name", "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)"));
console.log(objIndexOf(json.prices, "market_hash_name", "blah"));
```